# The issue with OAuth2 of using Google Calendar API in Android app

Tags: android, api, calendar

I've tried to implement Google Calendar API step-by-step according this link: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

I've enabled OAuth2 and Calendar API in my Google Developer Console.

But for the the some reasons when I would like to retrieve Calendar Events I see following log from Android Studio Logcat:

The following error occured: 
403 forbidden

```
"code" : 403, 
"errors": [
{
     "domain":"usageLimits",
     "message":"Access Not Configured. The API (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developer Console to update your configuration", 
     "reason":"accessNotConfigured",
     "extendedHelp":"https://console.developers.google.com"
}
],
"message":"Access Not Configured. The API (Calendar API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developer Console to update your configuration"
```

Could you help me with that problem, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message reads: You have to enable the Calendar API using the Google Developer Console. Consider https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth for further reading on this topic.

> ### Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0
>
> All requests to the Google Calendar API must be authorized by an
>   authenticated user.
>
> The details of the authorization process, or "flow," for OAuth 2.0
>   vary somewhat depending on what kind of application you're writing.
>   The following general process applies to all application types:
>
> 1. When you create your application, you register it using the Google Developers Console. Google then provides information you'll need
>      later, such as a client ID and a client secret.
> 2. **Activate the Google Calendar API in the Google Developers Console.** (If the API isn't listed in the Developers Console, then skip this
>      step.)
> 3. When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access.
> 4. Google displays a consent screen to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.
> 5. If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.
> 6. Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.
> 7. If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.
>
> Some flows include additional steps, such as using refresh tokens to
>   acquire new access tokens. For detailed information about flows for
>   various types of applications, see Google's OAuth 2.0 documentation.